# Android:Multi touch doesn't work as expected?

Tags: android

Help me in resolving the below issue.

I have three image buttons on screen. All these three buttons controlled under ontouchlistner as below.

buttonOne.setOnTouchListener(this);
buttonTwo.setOnTouchListener(this); 
buttonThree.setOnTouchListener(this);

I override "public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)". Under this i check for these three image buttons touch events like below.

```
ImageButton imageBtn = (ImageButton) v; 

  if ( imageBtn == buttonOne ) // first button touch 
                ..Log.. 
            else if ( imageBtn == buttonTwo ) 
                 ..Log.. 
  else if ( imageBtn == buttonThree ) // first button touch 
                ..Log..
```

My problem is, as it is under multi touch event handler like above, it does not detect when touch all three button at a time to try to produce multi touch effect, instead it detects only one imagebutton touch at a time even though i touch all three image buttons. As i am developing this project on Android 1.6 SDK, is there any problem accessing my requirement(multi touch) (or) it is a known issue? 
I am hoping that, when it works for single button touch, why shouldn't it work when clicking three imagebuttons at a time to produce three logs printed as per my above code?

How do i resolve it for my case?

Please don't question me why i am still developing on 1.6 for such a requirement.

Thank you. Appreciate your suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the multitouch support in 1.6 is limited to gestures. You might need to develop for android 2.x to get full multitouch support.

Comment: There is no multitouch at all in the 1.6 SDK, not even in Gestures.

Comment: Thanks Lunix and Casey. My last question, as my code(please see the actual query) is developed for multi touch, the same code should be able to capture multi touch scenario for three image btns on 2.x Android devices right?